# Windows 7 update error code 8024200d when trying to install update kb2918614

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I have a windows 7 64 bit computer that is failing to install the update `kb2918614`. It has installed all the other updates.

Every time it tries to install, it fails with the error code `8024200d` - it tries again every time I restart the computer.

I have tried renaming the `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\` to `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution.old` and installing again, but the same thing happens.

I have also tried running the "Windows Update System readiness tool", but that didn't work either.

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: try to install the MSU manually: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43743

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks! That worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error `8024200d` means `WU_E_UH_NEEDANOTHERDOWNLOAD (The update handler did not install the update because it needs to be downloaded again.)`

Download and install the Update with the help of the [MSU file from the downloadcenter](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43743), instead of using Windows Update.